# How to set plotting order of overlapping sf polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-sf

I have a set of overlapping sf polygons that I would like to plot on top of each other, the largest in the bottom and the smallest on top. This is default for SpatialPolygons, where the @plotOrder slot is based on the order of polygon areas, in decreasing order. But how can I achieve the same for sf objects (without converting to Spatial)?

Below is an example with the same polygons as Spatial and sf-objects :

```
library(rtop)
library(sf)
rpath = system.file("extdata",package="rtop")
obssf = st_read(rpath, "observations")
obssp = as(obssf, "Spatial")
```

The SpatialPolygons can be plotted nicely with spplot, small polygons are on top of larger ones, so they are all visible:

```
spplot(obssp, "QSUMMER_OB")
```

The same is not the case for the sf-object, whether I use plot or ggplot:

```
plot(obssf[, "QSUMMER_OB"])
ggplot(obssf) + aes(QSUMMER_OB, fill = QSUMMER_OB) + geom_sf()
```

How can I plot the polygons according to their polygon area with plot or ggplot for the sf-object, in the same way as spplot does for the SpatialPolygons?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `tidyverse` functions when using `sf`, so you can transform the data into `sf` and then order the polygons according to the `"AREASQKM"` property.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

obssf |>
  # Convert to sf
  st_as_sf() |>
  # Arrange according to areas attribute in descending order
  arrange(desc(AREASQKM)) |>
  # Make ggplot and set fill color to QSUMMER_OB
  ggplot(aes(fill = QSUMMER_OB)) + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image: geom_sf arranged]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan! Not as straightforward as I had hoped, but your solution works exactly as I wanted!